# luajit copy table is slow

Tags: memory, lua, lua-table, luajit

Within a larger lua-script, I have to copy several tables dt:

```
for i=1,dt:nrow() do
    local r = {}
    for j=1,dt:ncol() do
        r[j] = dt[i][j]
    end     
    rslt:append(r)
end
```

The tables are about 50,000 lines x 25 cols, containing mainly doubles. luajit takes about 10 times as long as "standard" lua. On all other calculations/operations I do before, luajit is faster (1.5 to 3 times).

Comment: You should use FFI arrays for fast data processing on numbers. Other than that, check the output of `-jv` and the profiler.

Comment: Would it be significantly faster if `dt:ncol()` be calculated before entering outer loop and `rslt:append(r)` be replaced with more simple code or be deferred?

Comment: I am calling the script from a lua state within a C++ program. FFI-arrays are no option as it shall also run with "standard" lua.

Answer (score 0):

As silly as this may sound, try pre-allocating the `r` table with 25 values:

```
local r = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
```

Unfortunately Lua API doesn't allow pre-allocation of tables, so this is the only way to avoid re-allocations caused by array assignment in the inner loop. My tests show noticeable improvement, but not close to 10x (although I don't use your methods, so your results may vary).

Comment: I also considered that. But unfortunately, the tables can also have different numbers of columns.

Comment: You can use loadstring, but it's likely to kill all the performance gains; another option would be to have an `if` statement that would allocate that table based on the desired number of columns.

Comment: You can also write a simple module to expose [lua_createtable](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_createtable) to your lua code, which would give you direct access to the initial number of elements in the table.